# Is <script src="file.js"> the same as <script src="./file.js">?

Tags: javascript, html

In an HTML file, are the following two script includes functionally equivalent?

index.html

```
  <script src="file.js"></script>
```

and

```
  <script src="./file.js"></script>
```

From what I remember, when files are resolved:

(1) The current directory of the HTML file is used by default for resolving relative paths,

(2) So "file.js" and "./file.js" are resolved using the path/directory of the HTML file.

When I experiment with this, they work the same in my test browser/server, but when it's behind an nginx load balancer with a route it is failing.  But I think this is a different issue which would be an entirely different question.

EDIT: The value of the PATH environment variable and the rules for executable files lookup are unrelated to the way that HTML `<script src="file.js">` is handled.

Comment: They should be the same unless you have an exotic nginx configuration ... I would look first in the nginx logs to see what errors are being emitted.

Comment: Not the same. First implies same directory. Second is a root relative path. So they would effectively be the same if the html file is in root only

Comment: @charlietfl Are you sure?  The second one starts with a `./`, which should mean the current directory.

Comment: Your browser should normalize both URLs to (the same) absolute URL before doing the request. Your server should not see any difference. Note that URLs are not relative to the HTML file's directory, but to the document's baseURL which can be changed in some circumstances (e.g when using a <base> element).

Comment: @Kaiido Post that as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

While the MDN docs for [script](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script) are not helpful, this article http://brianvanderplaats.com/2017/01/16/understanding-relative-urls/
covers the issue and explains how relative paths are handled.

### How it works

The way a script is handled is not determined by the server but is instead determined by the browser.  The browser parses the  element and makes an HTTP GET request to ask for the javascript file.

For example, if the following browser page were opened `http://host.com/app/dir1/index.html` and the following script element was found:

```
    <script src="file.js"></script>
```

When examined in Chrome's devtools I see that an HTTP GET for the file being sent to the server.

```
http://host.com/app/dir1/file.js
```

### What the standard says

The [HTML standard](https://www.w3.org/TR/2010/WD-html5-20100304/semantics.html) in *4.3.1 The script element* says:

> If the element has a src attribute, then the value of that attribute must be resolved relative to the element, and if that is successful, the specified resource must then be fetched, from the origin of the element's Document.

This means relative to the index.html file and then requested via the document's origin which is `document.location.origin`.  *NOTE: Technically, **the element** refers to DOM element but I'm keeping it simple.*

If we change the index.html file to include a dot, then we see the same HTML GET is issued.  So this:

```
    <script src="./file.js"></script>
```

Also results to the same HTTP GET being issued:

```
http://host.com/app/dir1/file.js
```

**Hopefully this clearly that `src="file.js"` is functionally the same as `src="./file.js"`.**

### Current is changed when `<base>` element is used

It is worth noting that if the `<base>` element exists, then it will be used instead of the *current* location.  For example,

```
<html>
  <head>
    <base href="https://just-a-test/dir1/">
    <script src="./file33.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>... rest not shown
```

Then the browser will issue an HTTP GET for

```
https://just-a-test/dir1/file33.js
```

Another interesting case is when a relative path uses a sub-directory, or dot-dot syntax to get to a parent directory `../images/img1.png`.

In both cases, the browser resolves the name and issues and HTTP GET Request for the resource it believes is the correct name.  So

```
<html>
  <head>
    <base href="https://just-a-test/dir1/">
  </head>
  <body>
    <img src="../images/img1.png"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

results in an HTTP GET request to the following file.

```
 https://just-a-test.com/images/img1.png
```

#### `<base>` can include filename

Lastly, the `<base>` element can include a filename such as:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <base href="https://just-a-test/dir1/index.html">
  </head>
  <body>
    <img src="img44.png"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

When this happens, the filename is dropped and only the remaining path is used so in this case an HTTP GET request is made for this file.

```
 https://just-a-test.com/dir1/img44.png
```

And not the file `https://just-a-test.com/dir1/index.html/img44.png`.

I bring this case up because a common bug is to leave off the trailing slash and wonder why things are not working.  For example,

```
<html>
  <head>
    <base href="https://just-a-test/dir1">
  </head>
  <body>
    <img src="img44.png"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Results in an HTTP GET Request to

```
https://just-a-test.com/img44.png
```

Which might make you think it wasn't working.  This happens because `dir1` is viewed just like `index.html` in the previous example and ignored for the purposes of issuing the HTTP GET requests.

Documentation on `<base>`

[The MDN documentation for base is here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base) and the HTML5 standard for `<base>` is [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/document-metadata#the-base-element).  My hightlights are:

- If the document has no  elements, then the browser uses location.href.  A base can include a filename.
- If multiple  elements are used, only the first href and first target are obeyed — all others are ignored.
- A base element must have either an href attribute, a target attribute, or both.
- The base element has to be put in the `<head>` element.
- The base element does not have a closing tag.

Comment: The origin has little to play here, it only sets the Origin HTTP header that the server could check to see if it's willing to share this resource, but that doesn't influence the URL. What does is the base URL of the element's Document. W3C's HTML specs are outdated, the true HTML standards are at whatwg. [There, at step 26.4](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#prepare-a-script), they ask to [Parse](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/urls-and-fetching.html#parse-a-url) `src` relative to the element's [node document](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-node-document).

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference between the two from web browser perspective.

However, on *nix systems, for example in shell, `file.js` would be searched in `$PATH`, while `./file.js` will be searched in current directory.

Comment: The statements on  `$PATH` are unrelated to the problem and IMO confusing your answer.  For example, whether you have the current directory on your path or not (e.g.,  `PATH=.:$PATH` ), the file `file.js` will be found in the *current* directory where current is defined as the directory relative to the HTML file that is including the file.

Comment: I don't know what nginx load balancer does or how it does it, but it was my hypothesis that it might be parsing the html and searching the file on the system, which could be using $PATH